# How to make std::string compatible with char*?

Tags: c++

I usually find some functions with `char*` as its parameter.But I heard that `std::string` is more recommended in C++. How can I use a `std::string` object with functions taking `char*`s as parameters? Till now I have known the `c_str()`, but it doesn't work when the content of string should be modified.

Answer (score 6):

For that purpose, you use `std::string::data()`. Returns a pointer to the internal data. Be careful not to free this memory or anything like that as this memory is managed by the string object.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Some people say if you read beyond the null terminator, you'll be able to find each and every internet page there. :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Evg At the very least, nobody can say you *won't* find them there.

Comment: @Evg don't try to make fun of me, I have seen [the internet](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/theitcrowd/images/9/92/FR55S2JG4PBP7TA.MEDIUM.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/180?cb=20151230224259) and there are no strings attached :P

Answer (score 6):

You can use the address of the first element after `C++11` like this:

```
void some_c_function(char* s, int n);

// ...

std::string s = "some text";

some_c_function(&s[0], s.size());
```

Before `C++11` there was no guarantee that the internal string was stored in a contiguous buffer or that it would be null terminated. In those cases making a copy of the string was the only safe option.

After `C++17` (the current standard) you can use this:

```
some_c_function(s.data(), s.size());
```

In `C++17` a non-const return value of [std::string::data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) was added in addition to the *const* version.

Comment: Presumably, the `some_c_function` will leave a `'\0'` terminated C-style string in the "buffer".  The string needs to be resized afterwards, because it's size includes the `'\0'` and the rest of the trailing fallow "buffer".

Comment: @Eljay That could be so. But I don't want to second guess what the `C` function might do. Some legacy functions don' t modify strings they are just lax about using `const`. Also a lot of functions simply fill the string buffer and return the length filled. There could be an alternative end value (like '\n') etc...

Comment: what was different before c++11?

Comment: Aye, good point.  I can think of several different ways a buffer could be used.  It may be used as a binary buffer, so a `'\0'` may just be data (as used for input only, for input/output, or output buffer only).  It may be just a C-style string for input (so a size should be irrelevant).  It may be a C-style string output buffer, so a size-as-a-buffer-limit to prevent overrun would be very important.  All depends on the API.

Comment: "*Before C++11 there was no guarantee that the internal string was stored in a contiguous buffer or that it would be null terminated.*" - true, but *in practice* MOST implementations actually were, because it kept the implementation of `c_str()` simple. And so when C++11 changed the requirements to require contiguous-ness and null termination, most implementations were already in compliance (that is probably one of the reasons why C++11 made the change in the first place, to make the common practice standardized).

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17 `std::string::data()` returns a pointer to the underlying `char` array that does allow to modify the contents of the string. However, as usual with strings, you may not write beyond its end. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data):

> Modifying the past-the-end null terminator stored at data()+size() to any value other than CharT() has undefined behavior.